# Scan folder with twig

Tags: php, twig, scandir, grav

I am doing my first steps with GRAV CMS and just get in contact with twig (as well my first steps).

For my template, I would like to scan a folder and echo each file in it. Usually I would use normal PHP and scandir and foreach but it seems as I can't use usual PHP-functions in my base-twig-file.
Is there a possibility to use scandir or anything else to scan a folder with twig?

Answer (score 4):

You can scandir as usualy in php file, and then send data to twig template

in yourphpfile.php

```
$dir    = '/tmp';
$array_files = scandir($dir);
$template = $twig->loadTemplate('index.html');
echo $template->render(array('files' => $array_files));
```

and in index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>My Webpage</title>
        </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            {% for file in files %}
                <li>{{ file }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds good, thank you. But when I create a PHP file, how can I tell GRAV to execute the function?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and stumbled across your question.
After some research I found out, that GRAV has these functions built in. More or less.
I know it has been a while, but better late than never :D

First: Add `content` to the front matter
`user/pages/pagename/pagename.md`

```
content:
    items: '@root'
    order:
        by: folder
        dir: desc
```

Second: Add list to the blueprint
`user/themes/themename/blueprints/pagename.yaml`

```
title: Downloads

'@extends':
    type: default
    context: blueprints://pages

form:
  fields:
    tabs:
      type: tabs
      active: 1

      fields:
        options:
          type: tab
          title: PLUGIN_ADMIN.OPTIONS

          fields:

            filelist:
              type: section
              title: File List
              underline: true

              fields:
                header.folders:
                  name: folders
                  type: list
                  style: vertical
                  label: Folders
                  fields:

                    .folder:
                      type: pages
                      label: Folder
                      show_all: false
                      show_modular: false
                      show_root: false
```

Third: Loop inside the template.
`user/themes/themename/templates/pagename.html.twig`

```
{% extends 'partials/base.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}

    {% for current in header.folders %}

        <h3>{{ page.find(current['folder']).title }}</h3>

        {% if page.find(current['folder']).media.files %}
            <h4>Files:</h4>
            {% for pFile in page.find(current['folder']).media.files %}

                {{ pFile.filename }}

                <br/>

            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}

        {% if page.find(current['folder']).media.images %}
            <h4>Images:</h4>
            {% for pImage in page.find(current['folder']).media.images %}

                {{ pImage.filename }}

                <br/>

            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

**So what does it do?**

The code above allows you to select certain folders and lists every file and image inside it. Videos and audio are ignored.
If you have the admin panel installed, you can select the pages inside the Options Tab of each page with the selected template.
Since you have the regular GRAV objects, you can easily access their `path`, `file names`, etc.